# How can I ask a Moderator to review a closed question?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I've seen a couple of questions that I believe accurately fit the description for what makes a good question on Stack Overflow. However, these questions were closed by users who must have only scanned the question. For example, this question:

[What is a stack overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110138/what-is-a-stack-overflow)

Was closed as "belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com", when quite clearly it is contrary to what makes a good Meta question, and in agreement with what makes a good Stack Overflow question.

I am wondering, is there a way I can contact a Moderator with the power to correct this mistake?

---

Additionally, maybe the amount of rep needed to close a question isn't high enough, as more users are achieving the needed rep who I don't consider to be responsible enough with the power.

And, how about if a question is closed and re-opened, it should take more close votes to close it a second time. Maybe the sum of the rep of users who voted to close should be weighed against the sum of the rep of the users who voted to reopen, and that should decide which way a question goes.

Comment: Yea when that question first came out it was mangled and very hard to read.  It seemed to me that they were asking about the site, not the consept.  It was frustating to see that after I realized it was a proper question, it was already closed by others like me that misread the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  You can flag it, and a moderator will see it.  But if anything I would expect to opposite to happen: moderator review is more likely to result in the question being closed permanently.  Generally, if 5 high-rep users voted to close, there's a reason for it.  There are excpetions, of course, so go ahead when you think you really find one of those.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Good answer. I was mistakenly thinking the flag feature was just for offensive items.

Comment: `Generally, if 5 high-rep users voted to close, there's a reason for it`. Does it imply that most humans are fair (and/or that humans are naturally socially smart?). Which one is more natural: selfishness (power abuse, censoring, being loyal to our friend at the expense of others, etc.) or extended cooperation? And why would the moderators/elected be fairer than the others? `. There are exceptions, of course` What if the exception was to be fair?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question you asked, you can use a custom flag to ask a moderator to look at something (as already noted in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4306/162102).

But to answer the underlying question, how to get a closed question reopened if you don't think the closure was warranted, a good approach is to raise the issue on the site's meta.  Link to the question, explain why you think it should be open, and ask people to review it.  Either people will vote to reopen or somebody will answer your meta post explaining why it really should be closed.  Moderators may be reluctant to unilaterally reopen, but you can get the community to do it (if it's warranted).

You can also bring it up in the site's main chat room.  (I don't know SO's rooms, beyond knowing that there are several.)

If a question either receives at least one reopen vote or is edited after being closed, it is automatically put in the reopen review queue where others are likely to weigh in.

Answer (score 0):

if the question was closed mistakenly it will be open promptly without moderator's intervention. don't worry.

Comment: Case in point: his linked question is open again.

Comment: and it shouldn't be, really.

Comment: Perhaps (even likely) it is a duplicate, but it should not have been closed as "belongs on meta".

Comment: Aha! The linked questions probably just been opened because some people followed my link from here to open it. Maybe this is the solution: complain about a mis-close here, and some people with sense who look at meta.stackoverflow will vote correctly.

Comment: @yshuditelu: well I closed it as not-a-real-question, but apparently majority decided otherwise.