# Why a question get closed in ASP.NET tag but get upvotes in PHP tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, closed-questions

Inspired by [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18525/how-to-complain-if-a-question-is-unjustifiably-closed/18539#18539) question  which says that I can post my concern here if I believe down voting/closing my question was unfair.

I have posted the question about [textbox preview like facebook in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091724/textbox-link-preview-in-asp-net) which not only got closed but downvoted too. Amazingly, no one has bothered to mention about the reason behind this.

I knew that this question will get close either by stating "not a real question" or "not constructive". Unfortunately, the same kind of question does well on PHP tag and get proper response (with votes up too) but when these questions comes up in ASP.NET tag it often get closed. Does the moderator of PHP doesn't care about the rules of SO or moderators of ASP.NET are quite sensitive? You can see multiple question on PHP tag asking the same thing but none of them is closed and some of them are upvoted too.

Please accept my apologies in advance for my English; I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: Asking for tutorials or links simply isn't a good question for SO. I don't know what PHP question you've seen that's similar, but if it is it might have to be closed as well. We want to answer actual questions regarding your problems. We don't want to be a collection of links to possible solutions.

Comment: The links to the PHP questions are in the question he posted and linked to.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Ah, thanks. I overlooked that, assuming they were all external.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, those PHP questions date back to 2011 and before, when such questions *were* on topic. Policies change, resource recommendation questions are no longer on topic.

So basically questions asking for tutorials are not constructive. In the case of simple things ("Could someone please give me a tutorial on how to create a circle on HTML5 canvas"), one can change a "Give me a tutorial" to a "how do I do this" type question ("How do I make an HTML5 canvas circle?").

However, your question is quite broad, which is why it was closed as Not A Real Question (which applies to broad questions). You're effectively asking the community to write an entire webapp for you. I don't see how this could be fixed, really.

Besides, [other stuff exists](http://enwp.org/WP:OSE) is in general not a valid argument on such online communities, due to the mutable nature of policy (and because things that need closing can be missed)

Comment: Can you help in understand what *such question* means in your answer. I will try to improve my question on the new rules.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: edited. Your particular question probably cannot be fixed, I suggest you ask for tutorials in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is essentially this:

> Can anyone guide me how I can implement the same with asp.net? Or how I can convert the existing code from php to asp.net?

Somebody could argue it is not a question, but a request for somebody to convert the code.
I understand why the question has been closed as not a real question: It is too broad. It doesn't show any code, but it gives 4 links for which only in one case the PHP code is visible in the linked page, and in one case the only visible code is JavaScript (the PHP code is only visible as "Link").

Looking at the question, it seems one of those "do the work for me" questions. That could not be how you wanted your question to come out, but that is probably what users see when reading it.

As per questions asking for tutorials, they are not anymore allowed. If you see them, you should vote to close them or flag them for moderation attention, if you don't have the privilege of voting to close.
The fact there are questions asked in the past about tutorials is not a reason for asking a question requesting tutorials nowadays. They are considered not constructive, since the purpose of Stack Exchange sites is not building a library of links, but a library of knowledge.