# Close votes justified?

Tags: discussion

I fail to see what is wrong with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163209/who-coined-the-term-zen-mode-textarea), or why it is considered not a real question.

I am following advise given in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18526/150082) -- and yes, the warning given has been taken and I would be actually grateful if I am made to see the problem with my question on SO.

Comment: I think "Off Topic" is a better close reason. It has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Probably because it is not "a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, software tools commonly used by programmers, or a practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession". Taken from [the site FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: This is very, very off topic.

Comment: Keep in mind that the fact that a site's audience might know the answer does not necessarily imply that the question is appropriate for that site.

Comment: @JonW Here is the thing -- I am developing a browser add-on relying on this concept and I wish I could give credit to whoever used the term first. I agree, not a frequently faced problem, but it is related to programming profession in this context.

Comment: @Majid Sideways perhaps. It's an etymological issue rather than a programming one.

Comment: I have a slight pain in my left foot. It's affecting my performance as a programmer, but asking about it would still be off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Bart, agreed; but those who may know the answer are more likely frequenting SO than etymology Q&As -- but I may be wrong there too.

Comment: WOW, you people deliver on [your promise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18526/150082)!

Comment: @Majid In addition to that link, you surely have seen this one as well? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @Bart yes, it kind of means *we don't share your POV*; that's fine by me.

Comment: Exactly. Don't take it personally. That said, perhaps there is a Wordpress or Github chatroom where you could ask the question. Maybe some of the people there can at least give you a hint?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's play my favorite game, Check the FAQ:

What kind of question can I ask here:

- a specific programming problem > **Nope**
- a software algorithm > **No**
- software tools commonly used by programmers > **No**
- practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession > **No, no, no**

That's `0` out of `4`...

Comment: Well, you had No's for the last point, so it's really 0 out of 6.

Comment: @JonW: Actually, it should be more like "0 + No", as the first three are optional, but the last one is not (really)...I think I need to write a tool for that or something...

Comment: They really should just implement this themselves. Click on "Why is my question closed?" then users can just go through the checklist for what to ask and what not to ask. "Now you know why."