# Which questions are closed?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I really want to learn which type of questions are closed. I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917573/comments-about-jython) to stackoverflow but actually it was not a real question i wanted some suggestions. It was something like "which IDE do you suggest for C++". It was a question which asks suggestion. But it was closed. The question about IDE suggestion gets stars, but my question is closed. Two of them ask the same thing: suggestion.

Then I asked the same question with [a different title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917926/do-you-suggest-to-use-jython) and got an answer but in a short time it was closed due to duplicate of my previous so I could not get another answer.

Also, i noticed that same content in these two questions got different reactions from people. First one got -8 votes and the other one got -1 vote. What i understand from these reactions that people do not read the content of the question. This is a really really big problem.

Comment: **Step 1:** Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq. **Step 2:** Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask **Step 3:** Ask a new question that meets those guidelines. **Step 4:** Profit!

Comment: I am not the one that uncomfortable with this kind of problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4301/how-can-i-ask-a-moderator-to-review-a-closed-question

Comment: I don't see how that question applies here.

Comment: It is worth noting that there are chat rooms for almost every language on SO, which is the correct place to ask for opinions.  You only need 20 rep to participate.

Comment: @Robert, It was closed although it was worth to be answered.

Comment: If you read the first comment under that meta question, you will see that the original question was poorly worded, and people thought the question was about Stack Overflow, the website, which is why it was originally closed. The original wording of the question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1110138/1 Questions do get closed in error sometimes; that's why we have moderators.  But that's *not* what happened to you.

Comment: @Robert, that is what I say: people do not read the content of the questions. They just vote to close.

Comment: Erm...No, people are voting to close your questions because *you are asking questions that are off-topic.* Questions that get closed in error are rare. Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/faq yet?

Comment: I do not know the error ratio but I hope you are right.

Answer (score 7):

Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a forum.  If you are used to the way traditional internet forums work, you're going to have to change it up a bit.  Stack Overflow doesn't work like those forums.

Everything you need to know to ask a question that will be accepted by the community is here: https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 4):

Typically questions that are considered (which is, obviously, an entirely subjective decision to make) outside the scope of Stackoverflow, as defined in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq/):

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- software tools commonly used by programmers
- matters that are unique to the programming profession

...are *most-often* not closed (unless they're duplicates).

Questions which are subjective, and without an objective 'right answer,' or which meet the following criteria:

- every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
- your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
- there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
- we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
- it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

...are very likely to be closed. Unfortunately for you, questions asking for 'comments' and 'suggestions' are, first of all, unable to be answered objectively and are also simply soliciting opinion, which is basically the first point in the above list.

Comment: “What’s your favorite __?” are very likely to be closed. Are you sure? You can see hunders of them in stackoverflow.See: http://www.google.com/search?q=What%E2%80%99s+your+favorite+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: @ndemir: Thanks for pointing those out. In the next few weeks, I will either close many of those questions, or add the following header to them: ***"This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here."***

Comment: Indeed, there's a few. Out of the first five I looked at three were originally asked in 2008, [one was asked this year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928126/book-suggestions-whats-your-favorite-book-site-tutorial-for-learning-about-numb) (and I've just voted to close as off-topic), and the fifth was asked in 2009. These questions were often asked in the early days of the site, before the proliferation of the trilogy (and then Stackexchange as a whole) which took over the majority of the non-explicitly-programming-related questions. They're artifacts, mostly.